# Package id emulator not avaible - Android Studio

Tags: installation, startup

I'm trying to install a virtual device in the Android Studio emulator but it won't let me and I get the Package id emulator error

Image of my mistake

[image: 1]

I tried to reinstall android studio but still got the same error and also tried to install android studio canary version. Adding that I'm on version 3.6.2